# How can i open .doc and ms office files in quickoffice without using filechooser in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I open .doc and ms office files in quickoffice in android without using filechooser.

Comment: You can't. Why would you want that anyways?

Comment: Without `Intent`? ohhhh.... I dont think any way to do this.

Comment: sorry, I mean to say filechooser. I directly should open my doc files in quickoffice

Comment: @Robi I am asking whether it is possible to open file in quickoffice directly without look for file chooser options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
It worked for me. I could able to get launcher activity by using Packagename  for getLaunchIntentForPackage method. 

         PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
         Intent quickOffice = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.quickoffice.android");
        startActivity(quickOffice);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I said.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think your problem is that if there are more than one application the user gets the option to select the app he wants to use.

You should not interfere with that. That's how the system is designed and how it should work. But if you really have to, you can use the full qualified name of the Activity Quickoffice uses as hook in their AndroidManifest.

For that you can look into their APK and check the manifest.

But again: That's not how it should be done.

**Bad practice. Very, very bad practice!**

Comment: But what i need is that I should embed quickoffice in my app so that i can able to open it in quickoffice without looking for suitable apps.

Comment: Bad luck. That's not possible.